# .NET timezone information

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

What is the standard format for datetime with timezone in a C# ASP.NET application?

Updated to clarify: In ASP.NET I need to check a datetime from a [Domino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Lotus_Domino) database against a .NET DateTime. The client is asking what would be the best format in which he should provide the datetime with the timezone. Meaning which format is most easily readable by .NET?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you give an example of what you want? Do you have some example code?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C#.net". Where did you ever hear of such a thing?

Comment: I need to check datetime from a dominos database against asp.net datetime. The client is asking what would be the best format in which he should provide the datetime with the timezone.-meaning which is easily readable by .Net.Let me know if this  gives a clear idea abt my question above?

Comment: Yes it does clarify your question. If that's what you actually wanted to know, I think you should have just asked that question in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** - regarding your clarification:

> I need to check datetime from a dominos database against asp.net datetime. The client is asking what would be the best format in which he should provide the datetime with the timezone.-meaning which is easily readable by .Net.

.NET supports parsing a wide variety of different formats so as long as it is in a fairly standard unambiguous format you should have no problem parsing it. But don't leave it to chance by relying on the default settings, use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx).

Check out the following resource for details on constructing the format string:

- [Parsing Date and Time Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)
- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

If you want to suggest something to him, then I would recommend following the [ISO 8601 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which looks something like this: `2010-05-14T10:04Z`. [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) can also understand this format without needing to provide a format string.

---

Answering your original question:

> What is the standard format for DateTime with timezone in a C# ASP.NET application?

Default formatting of DateTimes is based on the current locale. If you want a consistant format use either [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) or else a specific culture of your choice.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string s = now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Result:

```
"05/14/2010 21:17:35"
```

Note that the default formatting doesn't include the time zone. You can specify your own formatting though:

```
string s = now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zz");
```

Result:

```
"2010-05-14 21:21:59 +02"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default representation would be:

```
MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS (AM/PM)
```

But that also depends on the CultureInfo specified in the current thread. For a complete listing of options, use this MSDN resource:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant from a string to a DateTime object, the easiest way would be to use `DateTime.Parse("MM/DD/YY HH:mm:ss UTC-OFFSET")`, such as "03/01/2009 05:42:00 -5:00". More info is in the [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=VS.100).aspx) method documentation.